# How to link two square payment gateway accounts for two different woocommerce products?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to use two square payment gateway accounts for two different Woocommerce products. So when an order is placed on two products payment should go to respective square accounts. I know Woocommmerce multi vendor, product vendor plugins have similar functions. But still appreciate your suggestions.